# $.getJSON get silent error on retrieving data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I try to retrieve data from a JSon services but I have some problem and I'm not able to pass trough the debug process.

I retrieve data from this dynamique services : http://www.synergiescanada.org/json/otherpublicationbyid?synid=synergies:bcn.arbutus.215.3263 I validate the result with this tool http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and it look fine.

```
[
   {
      "name":"Dr. Andre Smith",
      "publications":[
         {
            "id":"synergies:bcn.arbutus.215.3264",
            "title":"Exploring death and dying through discourse",
            "uri":"http:\/\/journals.uvic.ca\/index.php\/arbutus\/article\/view\/3264",
            "date":"2010-10-18"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

But in another way when I use .getJSON method from jquery the it fail.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://www.synergiescanada.org/json/otherpublicationbyid?synid=synergies:bcn.arbutus.215.3263" , 
    function(json) {
    alert(json);
  });
</script>
```

The popup alert is never trigged and as I understand getJSON fail silently after having some king of error when he retrive my JSON data.

I try do debug with firebug I just found this into the Console about the headers

(sorry I can add image I'm new)

```
Response Headersview source
Date    Thu, 14 Apr 2011 20:24:49 GMT
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.5
Cache-Control   store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Disposition inline; filename=author.json
Last-Modified   Thu, 14 Apr 2011 20:24:49 GMT
Content-Type    application/json
Set-Cookie  SESS65d098c5115a6dff636c637d3c170001=c82ctlcfe0926dr45jrge1crf5; expires=Sat, 07-May-2011 23:58:09 GMT; path=/; domain=www.synergiescanada.org
Expires Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Connection  keep-alive, timeout=50, maxreq=60
Transfer-Encoding   chunked

Request Headersview source
Host    www.synergiescanada.org
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-CA; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110323 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.16
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language fr-ca,fr;q=0.8,en-ca;q=0.6,en-us;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Referer http://localhost/test/ajax.html
Origin  http://localhost
```

The same demo page trigger JSON api from flickr and it doesn't complain at all so it look as I miss something here. Maybe it's obvious.

If someone can give me a clue I'll appreciate.

Comment: Ajax doesn't allow cross domain requests and hence you getJSON call is failing because you are issuing the call from a page loaded from localhost to  http://www.synergiescanada.org which are two different domains.

Comment: Also, your `json` variable will be an object, not a string. You'll want to use `alert(json.name);` or `alert(json.publications[0].title);`

Comment: Thanks the goal was to trigger an alert. Even with "object" label it should mean that the request was sucessfull.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a cross-site scripting issue -- your trying to get data from localhost of an external site. A workaround could be to use PHP as a "proxy." See: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

Comment: Thanks Gary and Cybernate. I thought json request may be cross domain as difference to Ajax request. As I said I retrieve image from flickr with the example code from Jquery website and i'm not into flickr domain with this local page (I use the same call). So it work but not with the JSON from synergies wich I build and I try to figure why.

Comment: I finaly resolve the issue by stoping use cross site scripting. I use Ajax query to request the JSON.